# None vs Null is sqlite3 (replace None value with Null in sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite, null, case, coalesce

I try to select from my database in sqlite3 when I select some of columns return None value instead of Null and try some way like below code but non of them work for me

```
cur.execute("""SELECT dataNum,
                      COALESCE(dataNum,"Null") as dataNum
                      FROM C1
                      order by rowid""")

cur.execute("""SELECT dataNum,
                      IFNULL(dataNum,"Null") as dataNum
                      FROM C1
                      order by rowid""")
cur.execute("""SELECT dataNum,
                      CASE dataNum WHEN dataNum is NULL THEN "null" ELSE "null_ex" END
                      FROM C1
                      order by rowid""")
```

all of these way return  **{'dataNum': None}** that I want to be **{'dataNum': Null}** or **{'dataNum': "Null"}**
Is there any problem in my code or is there any way to do this ?

Thanks for Consideration

Comment: Beware, your select query returns 2 fields, the former is the original `dataNum` (that will contain `None` values), and the latter is the *cooked* value that will contain `"Null"`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta 
I know it I only want to the query return "Null" or a desired string value ("hello") instead of original dataNum values even I try to replace with IFNULL func but I don't get right answer

Comment: My remark was that you are selecting **2** fields in each of your queries. In you only want **1**, get rid of the initial `dataNum`: `SELECT IFNULL(dataNum,"Null") as dataNum FROM C1 order by rowid`

Comment: @SergeBallesta 
Thanks a lot, I'm in wrong way completely, I found my problem